# JavaFX Javadoc not working in Netbeans 8

Tags: javafx, javadoc, netbeans-8

Although JavaFX is provided with Java SE 1.8 JDK, Netbeans cannot find the Javadoc for it.

I have tried going to `Tools -> Java Platforms -> Javadoc -> Add URL` in order to add the [online Javadoc URL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/) but it did not worked.

Could this be a bug in Netbeans ?

Comment: You want to use the JavaFX ***2*** documentation with javafx 8??? Also I wouldn't recommend using the online docs instead of the sources that come with the JDK. The online docs are still missing e.g. `TableView.refresh`...

Comment: @fabian you are right. I have just edited my question and corrected the JavaFX javadoc URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is a bug in Netbeans but I have found a solution.
For some reason, although the JavaFX source code is provided with the JDK, the source package is not declared in Netbeans.

Go to `Tools -> Java Platforms -> Sources -> Add JAR/Folder`
Then search for your JDK installation folder and select the `javafx-src.zip`.

That's it !